# Playa // Entries // Category Archive?

Tags: playa, categories, entry, category-archive

So I have several Channel Data that I'm pulling into a Product page: Accessories, Options, Features, etc...

For Accessories I have all of the associated products pulled in, but now I want to pull in the categories for each product but only once. When I do this:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" field="{{embed:slug}_accessories}" disable="members"}
{categories}<div class="col-md-4">
<p><a href="{url_title_path='products/accessories/'}">{category_name}</a></p>
</div>{/categories}
{/exp:playa:parents}
```

But that just gives me all the Categories for each product over and over again. Obviously not what I want. I just want to find each Category and list it once along with a link to that product category page :)

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

I have tried this as well:

```
{exp:channel:category_archive channel="products_accessories"}
    {categories}
            <h3>{category_name}</h3>
    {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" field="{{embed:slug}_accessories}" category="{category_id}" disable="members"}
            <a href="#">{title}</a>
    {/exp:playa:parents}

    {/categories}
{/exp:channel:category_archive}
```

This gets me all of the entries in the appropriate category but I also get all of the other Categories too. I need a way to pass the Entry IDs that I want to the Category Archive.

**UPDATE 2 USING STASH**

I have also tried what the might Croxton suggested:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="cat_accessories" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" sort="asc" orderby="title" disable="members"}
      {categories}
         {stash:id}{category_id}{/stash:id}
         {stash:url}{url_title_path='products/accessories/'}{/stash:url}
         {stash:name}{category_name}{/stash:name}
      {/categories}
   {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- get unique list items only --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="cat_accessories" unique="yes"}
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <p><a href="{url}">{name} | {id}</a></p>
   </div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

I'm still just getting the category listed each time an entry loop is parsed (the entry detail page loops it through 6 times):

```
Category
Category
Category
Category
Category
Category
```

So I'm not sure what's happening with the `unique="yes"` parameter on the `exp:stash:get_list` tag pair.

When I run Template Debugging I get this:

```
(0.453361 / 16.55MB)      Stash: SET cat_accessories to value id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/bedding-1-4-corn-cob-nestpacks|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options|+|id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/single-use-cage-top-for-sipper-sack|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options|+|id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/single-use-cage-top-for-water-bag|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options|+|id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/single-use-cage-top-for-water-bottle|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options|+|id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/single-use-docking-tray|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options|+|id|=|102|&|url|=|http://animalcaresystems.dev/products/accessories/single-use-water-bottle-assembly|&|name|=|Single Use Caging Options
```

I'm assuming that Stash grabs the ID of the category to determine if the Categories are the same?

**UPDATE FINAL**

With Croxton's help I now have this:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="cat_accessories" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" sort="asc" orderby="title" disable="members"}
      {categories}
         {stash:id}{category_id}{/stash:id}
         {stash:url}{url_title_path='/products/accessories/'}{/stash:url}
         {stash:name}{category_name}{/stash:name}
      {/categories}
      {stash:product_title}{title}{/stash:product_title}
      {stash:product_image}{if products_accessories_images}<div class="accessories_image">{products_accessories_images limit="1"}<p><img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='/images/uploads/products/{image}'{sn_image_product_detail_accessories}}" alt="{alt}" class="img-responsive text-center" />{/products_accessories_images}</p></div>{/if}{/stash:product_image}
      {stash:product_content}{if products_accessories_content}<p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars='175'}{products_accessories_content}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>{/if}{/stash:product_content}
   {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- get unique list items only --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="cat_accessories" unique="id"}
    <h3>{name}</h3>
    <div class="col-md-4 accessories_listings">
        <p><a href="{url}">{product_title}</a></p>
        {product_image}
        {product_content}
    </div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The last thing I need is just all of the Products under that Category. I'm only getting ONE product although there are SIX under this particular category.

**GETTING ALL PRODUCTS UNDER CATEGORY WITH STASH**

**Missing Getting Products JUST in it's Category (almost there!)**

Okay I think I have what I want, please let me know if there's a better way of doing this :)

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="cat_accessories" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" sort="asc" orderby="title" disable="members"}
      {categories}
         {stash:id}{category_id}{/stash:id}
         {stash:name}{category_name}{/stash:name}
      {/categories}
   {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set_list name="product_info" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" sort="asc" orderby="title" disable="members"}
      {stash:product_url}{url_title_path='/products/accessories/'}{/stash:product_url}
      {stash:product_title}{title}{/stash:product_title}
      {stash:product_image}{if products_accessories_images}<div class="accessories_image">{products_accessories_images limit="1"}<p><img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='/images/uploads/products/{image}'{sn_image_product_detail_accessories}}" alt="{alt}" class="img-responsive text-center" />{/products_accessories_images}</p></div>{/if}{/stash:product_image}
      {stash:product_content}{if products_accessories_content}<p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars='175'}{products_accessories_content}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>{/if}{/stash:product_content}
   {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

    {!-- get unique categories items only --}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="cat_accessories" unique="id"}
        <h3>{name}</h3>
        {!-- get products that belong to this category --}
        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="product_info" parse_tags="yes"}
        <div class="col-md-4 accessories_listings">
            <p><a href="{product_url}">{product_title}</a></p>
            {product_image}
            {product_content}
        </div>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Thanks again for all of the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each related product could have individual category relationships, right? So If I understand you correctly, you want the aggregate of all categories assigned to the related entries.

You can do that with [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash):

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="cat_accessories" parse_tags="yes"}
   {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" field="{{embed:slug}_accessories}" disable="members"}
      {categories}
         {stash:id}{category_id}{/stash:id}
         {stash:url}{url_title_path='products/accessories/'}{/stash:url}
         {stash:name}{category_name}{/stash:name}
      {/categories}
   {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- get unique list items only --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="cat_accessories" unique="yes"}
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <p><a href="{url}">{name}</a></p>
   </div>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

**EDIT**

Aha, so you're url is dependent on the entry url title, not the category url title, and is therefore unique even for same categories. Is that intentional?

If you change `unique="yes"` to `unique="id"` (i.e. the id column must be unique) then you'll get only unique categories, however I'm not sure what you need to do with that url.

**EDIT 2**

You can use nested lists and match/against to list out unique categories and associated products. No need to repeat your Playa loop twice:

```
        {exp:stash:set_list name="product_info" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}

           {exp:playa:parents channel="products_accessories" sort="asc" orderby="title" disable="members"}

                {stash:product_url}{url_title_path='/products/accessories/'}{/stash:product_url}
                {stash:product_title}{title}{/stash:product_title}
                {stash:product_image}{if products_accessories_images}<div class="accessories_image">{products_accessories_images limit="1"}<p><img src="{exp:ce_img:single src='/images/uploads/products/{image}'{sn_image_product_detail_accessories}}" alt="{alt}" class="img-responsive text-center" />{/products_accessories_images}</p></div>{/if}{/stash:product_image}
                {stash:product_content}{if products_accessories_content}<p>{exp:eehive_hacksaw chars='175'}{products_accessories_content}{/exp:eehive_hacksaw}</p>{/if}{/stash:product_content}

                {!-- create an index for this product to match against --}
                {stash:categories}{categories}@{category_id}@{/categories}{/stash:categories}

                {categories}
                    {exp:stash:append_list name="cat_accessories"}
                        {stash:cat_id}{category_id}{/stash:cat_id}
                        {stash:cat_name}{category_name}{/stash:cat_name}
                    {/exp:stash:append_list}
                {/categories}

           {/exp:playa:parents}

        {/exp:stash:set_list}


        {!-- list unique categories only --}
        {exp:stash:get_list name="cat_accessories" unique="cat_id" orderby="cat_name" sort="asc"}

            <h3>{cat_name}</h3>

            {!-- list products that belong to this category --}
            {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="product_info" match="#@{cat_id}@#" against="categories" orderby="product_title" sort="asc"}
            <div class="col-md-4 accessories_listings">
                <p><a href="{product_url}">{product_title}</a></p>
                {product_image}
                {product_content}
            </div>
            {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: That nearly works, it just outputs each Product Category each time, so it looks like that unique="yes" parameter isn't working or something.

Comment: Sweet your updated one works! Now I just need to get the products below the Category Name too then I'm good to go!

Comment: Updating my Question one last time (hopefully) regarding getting the Products to appear in its appropriate category. Currently all products are showing up under all the categories.